# Can I use a combination of DOM-2 and DOM-0 in Events?

Tags: javascript, dom

See this code:

```
<span id="clickme">Cliquez-moi !</span>

<script>
    var clickme = document.getElementById('clickme');

    clickme.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        e.target.innerHTML = 'Vous avez cliqué !';
    }, false);
</script>
```

And this code:

```
<span id="clickme">Cliquez-moi !</span>

<script>
    var clickme = document.getElementById('clickme');

    clickme.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        this.innerHTML = 'Vous avez cliqué !';
    }, false);
</script>
```

Did you see what I just did there? Rather than using `e.target`which is the official DOM-2 I used `this.` which is the official in DOM-0 combined with `.addEventListener`, and guess what? It worked perfectly in the browser and makes more sense to me cuz I'm used to DOM-0. What do you guys think? Is this doable/correct?

***EDIT:***

When I tried something else, like changing this:

```
<p id="result"></p>

<div id="parent1">
    Parent
    <div id="child1">child N°1</div>
    <div id="child2">child N°2</div>
</div>

<script>
    var parent1 = document.getElementById('parent1'),
        result = document.getElementById('result');

    parent1.addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) {
        result.innerHTML = "Element's ID using mouseover: " + e.target.id;
    }, false);
</script>
```

With that:

```
<p id="result"></p>

<div id="parent1">
    Parent
    <div id="child1">child N°1</div>
    <div id="child2">child N°2</div>
</div>

<script>
    var parent1 = document.getElementById('parent1'),
        result = document.getElementById('result');

    parent1.addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) {
        result.innerHTML = "Element's ID using mouseover: " + this.id;
    }, false);
</script>
```

It didn't work, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The different behavior you are seeing has nothing to do with DOM versions.  The Document Object Model (DOM) [Level 2 Core Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/) is a superset and replacement for the DOM specifications that came before it.  No browser in use today implements only a Level 0 specification - in fact, I'm not even sure exactly what that is.  This [summary document](http://www.w3.org/DOM/DOMTR) links to DOM Level 1, 2, 3 and 4.

---

Per [the specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-interface), inside of the `addEventListener()` callback, `e.target` and `this` are not always the same thing.

If you attach an event handler to a parent element and are listening to an event that can occur on a child element, then `e.target` will be the DOM element that originated the event and `this` will be the element that you attached the event to.  So, if using events that bubble and attaching event handlers to parent events, then you need to choose which one you want to use.

If the event handler is attached to the same element that originated the event, then `this` and `e.target` will be the same element.